# Latex2e Vs Overleaf online editor

Tags: overleaf

I used to edit all my Tex documents using the online tex editor named "Overleaf" so far. I'm interested in submitting an article to some journal where they specifically mention that the manuscript should be edited using Latex2e editor. I need to know whether there's any online editing facility just like Overleaf for Latex, to get my files compiled using Latex2e editor. Also, would prefer if I can handle Latex2e environment using Overleaf online editor which will be very convenient to me rather than going for an offline editor. Is there any such possibility? NOTE: Latex2e is something unfamiliar to me, but no option, the journal's style guide does not compile properly in Overleaf without bugs.

Comment: overleaf is an online installation of the standard texlive tex distrubution, so you are using latex2e there. latex2e is not an editor it is the tex format you are using.  The same latex2e text may be used whether you write it in a local editor or copy it from this website or write it in overleaf.

Comment: It may be that the journal uses a custom class file that is not in the standard distribution and you need to copy it to your overleaf project. If you showed the error message you get, someone could help.

Comment: Journal uses a style guide (.sty file) together with the sample template (.tex file). I uploaded both in the same folder before compiling, but it popped out 2 errors. https://mmp.susu.ru/page/en/requirements (see sample.tex and vestnik.sty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

overleaf is an online installation of the standard texlive tex distrubution, so you are using latex2e there. latex2e is not an editor it is the tex format you are using. The same latex2e text may be used whether you write it in a local editor or copy it from this website or write it in overleaf.

The problem was with errors in the journal suppled template.

An overleaf project using the sample document and supplied file is here

https://www.overleaf.com/read/xyxsvytvrsnk

The TeX code in both is really  awful but if that is a requirement for submission you have to do what you have to do....

The first error is that `\No` is undefined, I think it is just supposed to make `No.` so I added

```
 \newcommand\No{No.}
```

It then runs without error but warns that

> Package babel Warning: No Cyrillic font encoding has been loaded so far.

so I added

```
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
```

It now runs without error.

Comment: Many thanks for this attempt